# Get value of global token register from local group

Tags: tex-core

Given the following sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\foo
\foo={foo}

\begin{document}
\the\foo,
\begingroup
\foo={bar}
\the\foo
\the\global\foo  % <-- fails
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

This fails with

```
! You can't use `\global' after \the.
```

My question simply is, is it possible to *get* the global value of `\foo` from within a local group? As I guess it's not, what are the suggested alternatives (especially with regard to speed and cleaning up scratch memory after parsing is done)?

Some background information: What I'm trying to do is to write a more complex parser in LaTeX where I use a global token register to store the rest of the input string. For building the final result, I need to maintain a list of sub-expressions for which I wrap my whole parser into a local group to have a list of scratch token registers. The number of used registers grows and shrinks while parsing.

With big inputs it may now happen that the number of used local registers clashes with the number of the global token register used for the input. So the idea was to somehow make sure that whenever I need to access the input string, only the global register is read/written.

Comment: you should only ever use a register for global access or local access otherwise you are likely to fill TeX's save stack, that is why the unallocated scratch registers 0-9 have the convention specified in the TeXBook that odd numbers are used for global and even for local use. There is no way to access the global value (it is stored on the save stack internally)

Comment: with no example it is hard to guess your use case, but if you need to be able to have local nested instances of your parser you should write it only using local assignments. or if you really need global assignments you need to maintain your own stack of vales and save  and restore them (the `blkarray` package has some comments about that)

Comment: Your concept of local/global doesn't make really sense when retrieving values. If you add more nesting groups you get a stack of values, foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4. Which one is the global one when you are in group 4? foo3 or foo1?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is no nested grouping involved here, I just open a single local group to get a clean stack of registers, and close it when I'm done. The global register is necessary with this approach as I have to get the final result out of the local group eventually

Comment: you do not need a global register for that `\expandafter\endgroup\the\foo` will escape a token register out of one level of grouping or if you want to re-assign it  `\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\the\foo}`

Comment: When you locally assign a value to a register, TeX will save in memory (in the “save stack”) the previous value for restoring it at the end of the group, but this saved value is not accessible.

Comment: You have more than 32000 token registers available; you should reserve a number of them for the “global” tokens and others (with different register numbers) for the “local” tokens. Do you perhaps need more than 10000, say?

Comment: @egreg No, the plain 256 would even be enough in my case. David's expansion trick works fine for a single register, but how would you generalize that to more than one global register? If I understand your approach correctly, you say I should start with the scratch registers at a number that high, that no clash with already used global registers is possible. But how would I find a suitable value for that, given that there could be a huge list of packages allocating global registers?

Comment: @siracusa allocate them yourself: just do 256 \newcount in your package and you have 256 registers to play with.